# How can I solve or plot the equation?

Tags: plotting, functions

How can I solve this?

```
Solve[y == E^(Sin[5 (x - 3/100 y)] + 1), y]

Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

This is actually what I want to do. (the closed form solution is not important though).

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  y /. Solve[y == E^(Sin[5 (x - 0.03 y)] + 1), y][[1, 1]]], {x, 0, 
  10}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you specify that the closed form of the equation is not important and that you only want the plot, try `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[y == E^(Sin[5 (x - 3/100 y)] + 1), {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: ContourPlot of the equation in question]

You may also want to familiarize yourself with `RegionPlot` and `DensityPlot`.

Comment: I tried with a similar equation. Why would this not work? It doesn't produce anything.  `ContourPlot[ 
 y == (0.1 Sin[5 x] - 1 - 30/100 y )^2, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]`

Comment: @hana The LHS and the RHS do not cross for that equation in the region of $x \in [0,10]$ and $y \in [0,10]$.

Answer (score 6):

- We can solve the original equation by `x` respect to `y`.

```
Clear[eqn, sol];
eqn = y == E^(Sin[5 (x - 3/100 y)] + 1);
sol = SolveValues[eqn, x, Reals]
Plot[sol /. C[1] -> Range[-5, 5], {y, 1, E^2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["y", 15, Blue], Style["x", 15, Blue]}]
```

[image]

[image]

- Use `ParametricPlot` to interchange `x` and `y`.

```
ParametricPlot[
 Thread[{sol, y}] /. C[1] -> # & /@ Range[-5, 5], {y, 1, E^2}]
```

[image]

- Reply to the comment @hana.

The new equation `eqn = y == (0.1 Sin[5 x] - 1 - 30/100 y)^2;` have not real solution.

```
eqn = y == (0.1 Sin[5 x] - 1 - 30/100 y)^2;
Reduce[Rationalize[eqn, 0], {x, y}, Reals]
```

> `False`

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `FindRoot`

```
pts = Table[{n, y /. FindRoot[y == (E^(1 + Sin[5 (x - (3 y)/100)]) 
         /. x -> n), {y, n}]}, {n, 0, 10, .1}]

ListLinePlot[pts, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
eq = y == E^(Sin[5 (x - 3/100 y)] + 1);
```

---

**Outline:**

(each section is independent from the others)

- **Getting an interpolation function using NDSolve**
- **Getting a quick list plot with FindInstance using periodicity**

---

#### Getting an interpolation function using NDSolve

Following the same method as a previous answer I [wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271973/86543) one can turn a non linear equation with parameters to a differential equation where the variable over which the differential equation is defined is one of the parameters of the original equation. Then one can (numerically) solve that equation.

The differential equation:

```
deq = D[eq /. y -> y[x], x]
```

An initial condition for the differential equation is needed:

```
y0 = y /. FindInstance[eq /. x -> 0, y][[1, 1]]
```

The output is a root object.

Solve the differential equation and plot the solution :

```
yinterp = NDSolveValue[{deq, y[0] == y0}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Check the error by verifying whether `yinterp` solves the original equation:

```
eq /. y -> yinterp[x] /. Equal -> Subtract  // 
 Plot[#, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "Error"] &
```

[image]

---

#### Getting a quick list plot with `FindInstance` using periodicity

```
{Mod[x, (2 Pi)/5], y} /. 
  FindInstance[eq, {y, x}, Reals, 1000] // ListPlot
```

[image]